# Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS):

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, redirect, user-data

What is this error:

```
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

I use PHP CodeIgniter and library [SimpleLoginSecure](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/SimpleLoginSecure/), this is my code:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
    redirect('admin/index');
}
```

---

How can I resolve this error?

Regards

Answer (score 9):

I'm guessing you get an infinite redirect loop: you get redirected to admin/index, this same code snippet is run again, redirecting to admin/index ad infinitum. You probably want to add a check to that snippet and only do the redirect if you're NOT on the admin/index page.

Comment: I had this happen to me and this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use redirect() function in your class's __construct().

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$self    = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$str2use = strrchr($self, '/');
$length  = strlen($str2use) -1;
@$fname  = substr($str2use, 1, $length);

if ($fname != "YOURPHPSCRIPT.php"){
    echo "<script>window.location='YOURPHPSCRIPT.php';</script>";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this with a blog I manage and it ended up being a problem with the URLs set in `wp_options`. We moved the domain of the dev server and while one of domain prefix changes took in the database, the other didn't. If your url is set for `http://domain.com`, try setting it to `http://www.domain.com`.

Just goes to show it always helps to start with double-checking your settings, both in `wp-config.php` and the db site settings.

Answer (score 0):

check maybe you loading "index" page again somewhere in your code when the index page loading.

redirect('admin/index');