# If session exists redirect to other page PHP

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have index.php and home.php pages. index.php is like landing page, but if user is logged in or if session exist, i want to redirect him from index.php to home.php, if he tries to access index.php. And that redirect part of code is in header.php, which is part of code that is included both in home.php and index.php. The problem is i think that i got stuck in redirect loop, `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` this is error i am getting. I think i need to say that if this is home.php stop redirecting, but i am not sure how to do that

This is my code in header.php

```
<?php include('database.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('Location: home.php');
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
```

home.php code

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('nav.php'); ?>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

index.php code

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<?php include 'nav.php';?>

   //Some code not relevant to question

<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

Comment: show index.php and home.php code

Comment: i'm guessing `home.php` includes `header.php` which causes an infinite redirect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 310 (net::ERR\_TOO\_MANY\_REDIRECTS):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911808/error-310-neterr-too-many-redirects)

Comment: Yea it does but i need header.php included in home.php

Comment: That other question doesn't provide answer for my question.

Comment: you've any rewrites happening?

Comment: Yea i am trying some but its not rly working. I guess this is kinda more logic then coding problem. I will figure something out.

Comment: you'd be best to check that along with posting what you're using in `.htaccess`

Comment: If, instead of having the header.php redirect when the userID is set, you include the log in form when it is not set and than exit. That way, whatever page they visit, they can log in from and not have to navigate back to it after logging in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many others have stated you end up in an infinite loop

You could solve it like this, define e.g. RESTRICTED before the header on pages where user need to be logged in

home.php:

```
<?php

define( 'RESTRICTED', true );

require( 'header.php' );

// etc

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php

require( 'header.php' );

// etc

?>
```

And the header:

```
include('database.php');
session_start();

if ( defined( 'RESTRICTED' ) ) {
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ) {
      header( 'Location: index.php' );
      exit();
    }
}
else {
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ) {
      header( 'Location: home.php' );
      exit();
    }        
}

?>
```

**EDIT:**

In response to the logout issue, with logout button, send them to index.php?logout=true

index.php

```
<?php 

include('database.php');
session_start();

if ( defined( 'RESTRICTED' ) ) {
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ) {
      header( 'Location: index.php' );
      exit();
    }
}
else {
    if ( isset( $_GET['logout'] ) ) {
      $_SESSION = array();
    }
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ) {
      header( 'Location: home.php' );
      exit();
    }        
}

?>
```

**EDIT 2**

In reply to comment, an example on how to handle logged in users

In all restricted pages:

```
define( 'RESTRICTED', true );
require( 'header.php' );
```

In all pages where you want to send users to home.php **if** they are logged in:

```
define( 'SEND_TO_HOME', true );
require( 'header.php' );
```

header.php:

```
<?php

if ( defined( 'RESTRICTED' ) ) {
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ) {
      header( 'Location: index.php' );
      exit();
    }
}
else {
    if ( isset( $_GET['logout'] ) ) {
      $_SESSION = array();
    }
    if ( defined( 'SEND_TO_HOME' ) && isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ) {
      header( 'Location: home.php' );
      exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I like this, the only thing is if i go to some other page and user is logged in this still redirect me to home.php (for example if i go to logout.php and header.php is included before rest of code). But it think i get what you are saying. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: That edited part of code is that for index.php or header.php, also what about other pages, do i have to write code for other pages like you did for logout.php.

Comment: Its for header.php - i would show user any public page even if they are logged in, but show them an "go to account" link if logged in. But I'll edit in a 3rd solution for you.

Comment: You are right, i have register form on index.php and i could create separate register.php file but this is just for learning purposes so my goal is to learn and figure out best way to do this not just get it to work.

Comment: This is a simple way of doing it, but its not checking if the users session id is valid etc.I would prefer to define a constant on those pages available to anyone, this way you always restrict new pages as long as you dont specify it is public.

Comment: Just tried it, everything works, again thanks a lot. What do you think about my answer is that bad approach?

Answer (score 0):

Make a PHP file called `authenticate.php`

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

those file need authentication include this on that file like in you home page use `include('authenticate.php');`
In you index.php file make a form like

```
<?php
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
?>
```

In `process.php` do the following

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//make authenticate this info to your database if user is valid then redirect to home page

session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = 1;//here id will be the retrive id from your database
header('Location: home.php');
exit();
?>
```

Comment: If i understand this correctly this is in case that user goes to home.php and he is not logged in, but i need redirect if he is logged in, from index.php to home.php. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes you are Right,See My latest code it will help you @NenadVracar

Comment: I am sorry but that code you added is not relevant to my question. Thanks for you effort anyway.

Comment: ok, From you header.php file remove header portion `if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('Location: home.php');
    exit();
}` to seperate file and include it to index.php only otherwise it causes  infinite redirection