# Too many redirects. XAMPP ; Localhost; MYSQL (PHPMYADMIN)

Tags: php, xampp, http-redirect

I am using XAMPP for connecting a DB with PHP myadmin and a test-webpage which runs on a localhost Webserver via Apache. 
I uploaded all files to the htdocs folder. When I now run the webpage and try to "register" for that dummy-page on localhost the Browser throws the error-message: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS . 
Supringsingly, the data I send with the "sign up-button" is written in the DB, which I can check via the PHP myadmin console.

I think it is a problem of htacess and I have questions about that.

Where should the htacess file be? In the same directory with my other files? 
What should be in the htacess file? I dont want to upload it to the internet, so it is just for learning purposes and should stay in localhost.

I hope I could describe the problem well enough.
First my Index File:

```
<?php

session_start();

$error = "";

if(array_key_exists("logout", $_GET)){

    unset($_SESSION);
    setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
    $_COOKIE["id"] = "";

}else if(array_key_exists("id",$_SESSION) OR array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE)){

    header("Location: loggedinpage.php");

}


if(array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)){

    include("connection.php");


    if(!$_POST['email']){

        $error .= "Die Emailadresse fehlt<br>";

    }

    if(!$_POST['password']){

        $error .= "Passwort wird benötigt<br>";

    }

    if($error != ""){

        $error = "<p>Es gab Fehler in deinem Formular</p>".$error;

    }else {

        if($_POST['signUp'] == '1'){

               $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."' LIMIT 1";

                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                    $error = "Diese email ist bereits vergriffen.";

                }else{

                    $query = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."',
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'])."')";

                    if(!mysqli_query($link, $query)){

                        $error = "<p>Registrieren hat nicht funktioniert, versuche es später noch einmal.</p>";                    

                    }else{

                        $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '".md5(md5(mysqli_insert_id($link)).$_POST['password'])."' WHERE id = ".mysqli_insert_id($link)." LIMIT 1";

                        mysqli_query($link, $query);

                        $_SESSION['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($link);

                        if($_POST['stayLoggedIn'] == '1'){

                            setcookie("id", mysqli_insert_id($link), time() + 60*60*24*365);

                        }

                        header("Location: loggedinpage.php");

                    }
                } 


        }else if($_POST['signUp'] == '0'){

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            if(isset($row)){

                  $hashedPassword = md5(md5($row['id']).$_POST['password']);

                    if($hashedPassword == $row['password']){

                        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

                        if($_POST['stayLoggedIn'] == '1'){

                            setcookie("id", mysqli_insert_id($link), time() + 60*60*24*365);

                        }

                        header("Location: loggedinpage.php");

                    }else{

                        $error = "Deine Email Passwort Kombination konnte nicht gefunden werden.";

                    }

            }else{

                 $error = "2 Deine Email Passwort Kombination konnte nicht gefunden werden.";

            }


        }




    }





}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 310 (net::ERR\_TOO\_MANY\_REDIRECTS):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911808/error-310-neterr-too-many-redirects)

Comment: Do you think it is rather a code-problem than a htacess problem?

Comment: Yes, I would advise to break down the code into smaller parts and see at what point you start getting errors.

Answer (score 2):

This is the offending code:

```php
if (array_key_exists("logout", $_GET)) {
    unset($_SESSION);
    setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
    $_COOKIE["id"] = ""; // <-- Here is the problem
} elseif (array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION) OR array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE)) {
    header("Location: loggedinpage.php"); //                     ^-- and here
}
```

Notice how you are setting your `$_COOKIE['id']` to a blank string but the key still exists?
That's the problem, that means that the else-if is going to see that the key 'id' exists and then redirect using the header function on that code block.

To fix this just change the line to the following:

```
unset($_COOKIE["id"]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this does not change the behavior. 
If it is because of the code, I think it must be some line which has to do with the "sign up" or after it...
Do you have another idea?

Comment: @user9167430 I'm going to assume that it is the problem I posted the solution for, but is appearing somewhere else. Rather than setting the ID to an empty string, just unset it. Do this everywhere that you write `$_COOKIE['id'] = '';`. The other thing might be the `array_key_exists`, instead consider checking for `if (!empty($_SESSION['id']))` instead